# Php Regex - How to pick if equals something

Tags: php, regex, pdf

```
class Something

{

    public static function compile(&$subject, $replace, $with) {

        $placeholders = array_combine($replace, $with);



        $condition  = '{[a-z0-9\_\- ]+:[a-z_]+}';

        $inner      = '((?:(?!{/?if).)*?)';     

        $pattern    = '#{if\s?('.$condition.')}'.$inner.'{/if}#is';



        while (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match)) {

            $placeholder = $match[1];           

            $content     = $match[2];



    // if empty value remove whole line

    // else show line but remove pseudo-code

    $subject = preg_replace($pattern,

                            empty($placeholders[$placeholder]) ? '' : addcslashes($content, '$'),

                            $subject,

                            1);

        }

    }

}
```

I have a html code area to play on. Dompdf handles the rest for converting my form to pdf. This class code was almost premade. It gives me freedom to use ;

```
 {if {dil:value}} <div class="english">ENGLISH</div> {/if}
```

something like that in html area. But it was only checking if radio button is empty or not. But I want to learn which option is selected. So I want to use a code like ;

```
 {if {dil:value}=='ENGLISH'} <div class="english">ENGLISH</div> {/if}
```

I converted empty check line with manual equality check to see if it works;

```
        // if empty value remove whole line

        // else show line but remove pseudo-code

        $subject = preg_replace($pattern,

                                $placeholders[$placeholder]=='english' ? '' : addcslashes($content, '$'),

                                $subject,

                                1);
```

And it worked but without a freedom of course(only if radio equals to english). I'm so new to regex, so I couldn't figure it out. I tried to add $equality variable so I would use my code many times with different checks;

```
class Something

{

    public static function compile(&$subject, $replace, $with) {

        $placeholders = array_combine($replace, $with);



        $condition  = '{[a-z0-9\_\- ]+:[a-z_]+}';

        $inner      = '((?:(?!{/?if).)*?)';

        $equality   = '(?<=~)[^}]*(?=~)';

        $pattern    = '#{if\s?('.$condition.')'.$equality.'}'.$inner.'{/if}#is';



        while (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match)) {

            $placeholder = $match[1];           

            $content     = $match[2];



            // if empty value remove whole line

            // else show line but remove pseudo-code

            $subject = preg_replace($pattern,

                                    $placeholders[$placeholder]==$equality ? '' : addcslashes($content, '$'),

                                    $subject,

                                    1);

        }

    }

}
```

with this code on html area;

```
{if {dil:value}~'ENGLISH'~} <div class="english">ENGLISH</div> {/if}
```

I really believed that it would work, but it didn't :) Even pattern didn't get erase after converting to pdf so I can read my code under the pdf file.

I may be missing something about $match too. With equality variable included so $match might get third array I guess. So I also tried to add this but that didn't work too;

```
   while (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match)) {

        $placeholder = $match[1];  

        $equality   =  $match[2];     

        $content    = $match[3];
```

Well my goal is to put check icons on to specific box areas on premade designed form image. I handled all textboxes with absolute positions except getting which radio button is checked.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this;

```
class Something
{

    public static function compile(&$subject, $replace, $with) {

        $placeholders = array_combine($replace, $with);



        $condition  = '{[a-z0-9\_\- ]+:[a-z_]+}';

        $inner      = '((?:(?!{\/?if).)*?)';

        $equality   = '(~[A-ZÇŞĞÜÖİçşğüöı]+~)';

        $pattern    = '#{if\s?('.$condition.')}'.$equality.''.$inner.'{\/if}#is';



        while (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match)) {

            $placeholder = $match[1];           

            $equality    = $match[2];

            $content     = $match[3];

            $equality = substr($equality, 1, -1);

            // if empty value remove whole line

            // else show line but remove pseudo-code

            $subject = preg_replace($pattern,

                                    $placeholders[$placeholder] == $equality ? '' : addcslashes($content, '$'),

                                    $subject,

                                    1);

        }

    }

}
```

I changed my equality regex to support Utf-8 characters plus changed other regexes a bit. There were non excaped slashes. And finally I can use it at html like this;

```
{if {language:value}}~FRENCH~<div class="english">ENGLISH</div>{/if}
```

So first match gets radio button value, second match is my equality check, and third match is what will be written if equality is wrong. Yep I know it sounds a little bit reversed mode :) So it probably won't work with radio buttons which have more than 2 options. But in my situations my all radio buttons have 2 options.

So far so good, I kinda learnt regex today :)